# UITableView changing things of some cells in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a **UITableView with a custom UITalbeCellView**. Every cell has a title a body and a date. When I fetch the data **some of the titles must be red** so there is a Bool that is set to true for those cells which title has to be red.

**The first time the data is fetched it looks fine, but as you scroll up and down a few times all of the titles end up being red**.

Im using an array of structures to store the data and on the cellForRowAtIndexPath there is an if and if the boolean in that position of the array is true I change the color to red:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentsRowTVC", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentsRowTVC
let single_comment = self.AOS[indexPath.row]

cell.titulo_comentario?.text = single_comment.titulo_comment
if single_comment.flag == true {
    cell.titulo_comentario.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Im gessing it reuses Views or something like that. Does this have any easy fix? Or do I have to implement my own TableView to prevent this from happening?
Im also thinking the method **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** might be the one causing my problem... but Im new on swift and cant think of any replacement for that.

It is happening similar thing on buttons there are on the cells, when you click a button from a cell it changes its color and disables it, but just the one on that cell. However when clicking on a cell, buttons from other cells are also suffering those changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since cells get reused you end up with cells that were previously red because they had`single_comment.flag == true` and are now used for another row where there actually is `single_comment.flag == false`. You have to reset the color in the `else` branch again:

```
if single_comment.flag == true {
    cell.titulo_comentario.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
} else {
    cell.titulo_comentario.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

`UITableView`s reuse their cells, meaning that you will get cells inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which have previously been used before, maybe have have set the `textColor` to red. Your job is it now to revert the color of the text to its original state.

In general whatever change you make inside the `if`-branch of cell-customization has to be undone in the `else`-branch. If you remove a label in the `if`, add it in the `else`.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you. However when I change the color of buttons Im doing so from a function called from cell.myButton.addTarget. How could I revert those changes?

Comment: @PabloDuque I try to NEVER change the cell outside of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I try to reflect all properties that specify the display of a cell in a custom data structure and whenever a cell needs to change I change the corresponding property in the data structure and reload the row or the entire tableView.

Comment: how can I read a button click from the  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`??

Comment: @PabloDuque you dont. But you have an array of `AOS` where you probably some instances of a custom class stored. I would add a property to that class called "clicked" and then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` display the cell in different style according to wether or not `clicked` is set.

Comment: its kinda complex because I got some data on a cloud DB that I have to update when button is clicked and some data changes are local but your idea should work. Thank you very much!!